# Python cannot find/read folder with cedilla (ç) in name

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

I have a folder with name "ADOLFO DE MENDONÇA".
I ask python to list the files inside this directory:

```
files = os.listdir('E:\ADOLFO DE MENDONÇA')
```

Then, it yields the error:

```
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'E:\ADOLFO DE MENDON�A'
```

If I change the Ç letter to the C, it works.
Surprisingly, python correctly processes the inside files which contain cedilla (ç) in the name.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: It could be encoding issues or case sensitivity. What happens if you list the parent directory? Also note, the error message doesn't correctly print out the special character. Are you using the correct encoding?

Comment: Also note that in Windows, you need to use ```\\``` as the path separator.

Comment: Same happens when ~ is present. Let's say JOÃO.

Comment: @EricJin, I am not sure how to set encoding settings. I am Brazilian and need to deal with such language marks all the time.

Comment: @ewong, I subtracted the parent directory and the double slashes to make it simpler to see, but I used it.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Unicode handling is significantly different. Having said that - it seems this is more of a Windows issue

Comment: Your string contains literal backslash characters, so they need to doubled like `'E:\\ADOLFO DE MENDONÇA'` *or* an `r` string prefix must be added to it. i.e. `r'E:\ADOLFO DE MENDONÇA'`. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals). I don't think the Ç letter has anything to do with it.

Comment: If the Ç letter displays incorrectly as shown in the error message, you may need to set the System locale to your language. See [How do I view and change the system locale settings to use my language of choice?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.html)

Comment: What does `pathlib.Path.exists(r'E:\ADOLFO DE MENDONÇA')` return (after an `import pathlib`)? Also note that in Python you can use forward slashes in Windows paths, such as `'E:/ADOLFO DE MENDONÇA'` and not have to worry about possible backslash issues.